# WPF ContextMenu still visible after launching an external process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu

I'm launching an external application from a ContextMenu, and I **must** block the the source application while the target application is running. To achieve this I'm using `Process.WaitForExit()` to avoid the source application responding to events.

The problem is the context menu is still ahead the target application. Let's see it with a simple example:

[image]

This is the code I'm using for the example.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem();
        menuItem1.Header = "Launch notepad";
        menuItem1.Click += MyMenuItem_Click;
        this.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem1);
    }

    void MyMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();
    }
```

How could I make the ContextMenu to disappear before the target application is displayed?

Comment: In your click handler, you can set the visibility of the context menu and restore it after you get the exit signal. But for this to work you need to set the visibility in a Task.Run() statement.

Comment: By the way, **finally** a good question, with a reproduceable minimal example which you can just copy&paste and test things with. Gets a deserved +1, unlike most of the latest questions I see on S.O. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the great ideas given by [Jcl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68972/jcl)...

I found a simple solution using custom MenuItems for the menu. It delays the `MenuItem.Click()` event until the parent `ContextMenu` is closed.

```
class MyMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        ContextMenu parentContextMenu = Parent as ContextMenu;
        parentContextMenu.Closed += ContextMenu_Closed;
        parentContextMenu.IsOpen = false;
    }

    void ContextMenu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu parent = Parent as ContextMenu;
        parent.Closed -= ContextMenu_Closed;
        base.OnClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Does it work with commands? I thought it was not the click implementation that called them, but seems it indeed is!

Comment: @Jcl: Yes,it works. The command associated with the MenuItem is executed in the Click logic of the MenuItem, so it's a valid solution.

Comment: Cool then. Good job!

Comment: I'm having trouble making this work when the MenuItem is nested in another MenuItem. I can traverse up the tree and grab the root ContextMenu, but when I call base.OnClick(), it doesn't fire the original command. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I write after so long time, but I am having exactly the same issue, I am trying Daniel Penalba's solution, but I meet a problem : how can I add these custom MenuItem in XAML?

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, this seems to work ok:

```
void LaunchAndWaitForProcess(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    this.ContextMenu.Closed -= LaunchAndWaitForProcess;
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
}
void MyMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ContextMenu.Closed += LaunchAndWaitForProcess;
}
```

Since (in the comments) you say you are using `ICommand`s, I guess you are binding them in XAML and don't want to lose that.

A general-purpose way (ugly, and won't allow you to have `CanExecute` bound to the `Enabled` state of the menuitem, but the least ugly I could figure out in so little time) could be binding them to another property (for example: `Tag`), while also binding to a single `Click` handler. Something like:

In the XAML:

```
<MenuItem Header="Whatever" Tag="{Binding MyCommand}" Click="MenuItemsClick"         
<MenuItem Header="Other Item" Tag="{Binding OtherCommand}" Click="MenuItemsClick" />
```

In the code-behind:

```
private ICommand _launchCommand;
private object _launchCommandParameter;

void ExecuteContextMenuCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
   this.ContextMenu.Closed -= ExecuteContextMenuCommand;
   if(_launchCommand != null && _launchCommand.CanExecute(_launchCommandParameter))
     _launchCommand.Execute(_launchCommandParameter);
}

void MenuItemsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mi = (sender as MenuItem);
    if(mi == null) return;
    var command = mi.Tag as ICommand;
    if(command == null) return;
    _launchCommand = command;
    _launchCommandParameter = mi.CommandParameter;
    this.ContextMenu.Closed += ExecuteContextMenuCommand;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer: Sorry, I tested your code, but the context menu is still ahead the target app!

Comment: @DanielPeñalba try doing `this.ContextMenu.IsOpen = false;` before invoking the empty delegate on the dispatcher

Comment: @DanielPeñalba I just tried it and it didn't work... let me do some tests

Comment: This also doesn't work. I'm a little bit frustrated, the unique solution I found is the combination of `thread.wait(150ms)` + `event pump`, what is a very ugly solution.

Comment: @DanielPeñalba I'm making some tests and this is actually working... the problem is that the menu is doing a fade-out animation which seems to be controlled on the UI thread. If you set the system animation to none, it actually closes. I'm trying to find a solution to this. Guess you could open the process on the menu closing

Comment: Yes, this is the solution proposed by @Sinatr, but this become a problem when you have several MenuItems.

Comment: @DanielPeñalba check my update, this should work just fine even if you have multiple menuitems. Just remember to unsubscribe to self on each action

Comment: PS: *I promise I was testing this **before** seeing @Sinatr 's answer* :-)

Comment: @Jcl, no problems, it took me some time too to figure *when* is the right moment ;) (I was struggling with `Dispatcher.Invoke` and even `Task.Run` while trying to close menu earlier).

Comment: Arrg, thanks for the answer, this could be a solution. The hard part is that my application is executing the actions through `MenuItem.Command` instead in `MenuUItem.Click`. Maybe some refactor can help here. Frustrating is the word today.

Comment: Yeah, I get your frustration. I left WPF a while ago because of silly little things like this. I guess you could have a `Click` handler in your view execute the command. Not elegant since you won't be declaring the command in the XAML, but could work

Comment: @Jcl: Awesome work! Also, based on your idea I I found very a simple solution, take a look to my answer ... It's great to find people like you in SO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to start process when menu is closed:

```
bool _start;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    var menuItem = new MenuItem() { Header = "Launch notepad" };
    menuItem.Click += (s, e) => _start = true;
    ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
    ContextMenu.Closed += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (_start)
        {
            _start = false;
            using (var process = new Process() { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe") { CreateNoWindow = false } })
            {
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Tested and seems to work, but I doubt if idea with blocking UI thread for a long time is a good idea.

Comment: Bad solution if you have several MenuIItems. I prefer managing the event in the MenuItem click. Otherwise, if I have a context menu with several and I must differenciate the MenuItems click, the code could become ugly.

Comment: Well, you can store reference of last clicked menu item (it will be `null` if nothing is clicked) and check this reference to see what was clicked, etc. Problem here is what you are blocking UI, so nothing what is in progress can continue. Menu has animation. You have to wait for it (by using delay? event is more clear) or disable it and still do some tricks to hide menu before running process, because of wpf redraw nature (it's not instant, it's always some times later via Dispatcher).

Answer (score 1):

Blocking the UI thread (drawing, Window interaction) makes horrible UX: it looks like the application is frozen, which it actually is. I would go like this given the constraints:

```
void MyMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    Title = "Waiting for Notepad to be closed.";
    executeBlocking(p, () => {
        Title = "Finished work with Notepad, you may resume your work.";
    });
}

void executeBlocking(Process p, Action onFinish) {
    IsEnabled = false;
    BackgroundWorker processHandler = new BackgroundWorker();
    processHandler.DoWork += (sender, e) => {
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit(); // block in background
        p.Close();
    };
    processHandler.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) => {
        IsEnabled = true;
        onFinish.Invoke();
    };
    processHandler.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Disabling the Window itself (`IsEnabled = false`) will achieve *"I must block the source application"* by not letting the user interact with your app, other than Moving, Resizing and Closing it. If you need to block exiting as well you can do so like this:

```
InitializeComponent();
Closing += (sender, e) => {
    if (!IsEnabled) {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you must close Notepad to exit the application");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
};
```

It should be also general courtesy to the user to indicate you're waiting for notepad and once that's finished (closed) your app will be usable again, I did this in the window `Title` for simplicity and due to lack of any controls in the demo app.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This won't block the main application so if that is necessary, this answer won't work for you**

The ui thread is being blocked so it can't undraw the context menu. Why you can see it over other programs likely has to do with how it is drawn on the screen. As noted in the [Process.WaitForExit docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx)

> WaitForExit() makes the current thread wait until the associated
>   process terminates. It should be called after all other methods are
>   called on the process. To avoid blocking the current thread, use the
>   Exited event.

So you need to change your code to this

```
void MyMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
        p.Start();
    }
```

and then

```
private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       //Do whatever logic you have for  when the program exits
    }
```

Comment: `WaitForExit` is a requisite for me. I need to block the source application!

Comment: Ah okay, well I will leave my answer up in case someone stumbles upon your question without that requisite :)

Comment: @GordonAllocman if anyone doesn't have the requisite of blocking the source application, then this is a non-issue: the menu will close just fine.

Comment: @Jcl but they might be using WaitForExit not realizing they should be using Exited instead. If you really think my answer is completely useless I will delete it

Comment: @GordonAllocman what I think is irrelevant, it's important whether **you** think this might be pertinent to the question. I think that given the title of the question, it is not (this question is very specific). For the record, I haven't downvoted you, I'm just commenting :-)

Comment: @Jcl I think it's good to leave it here, in case someone finds this unrelated to the OP's question: they'll know why it is happening if they did it by accident. I don't know about you, but most of the time Google doesn't care about the meaning of the SO question if the contents match your keywords, in this case: "contextmenu visible process".