# ContextMenu stay on first plan

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I have a Context menu that is working correctly except in one situation :
When I want to execute a process, the context menu stays on first plan, and so it disturbs for using application I opened, maybe this is because I am waiting for the process to finish?

Here is the code of the WindowForm I open for launching process :

```
public Process process { get; set; }
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public bool finished { get; set; }
        public ExecuteProcess(string a, string b,string entete,string message)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.process = new Process();
            this.A = a;
            this.B = b;
            this.Text = entete;
            this.label1.Text = message;
            finished = false;          
        }
        private void ExecuteProcess_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo Install332 = new ProcessStartInfo();
                Install332.FileName = this.A;
                Install332.Arguments = this.B;
                this.process = Process.Start(Install332);
                this.process.WaitForExit();
                this.finished = true;
                this.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "");
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteProcess_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!this.finished)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

I open a WindowForm that will make appear desired message, launch the process, and keep opened until process is finished. I have two situations :

1) I execute an application so it opens a new window, but context menu stays in first plan.

2) I execute an external basic file, and WindowForm appears until process is finished.

I also put a prinscreen in case it would be of any help :

[image: Context stay on front]

**Edit** : Maybe useful information, context menu is defined in a ListView (WPF)

Comment: Couldnt you just close the context menu? Im not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Either you close the context Menu like Nicolas said, or use a Task<string> to run the  Process. After the await, you can use the string returned to check if anerror occured and then show the message box... is anyway better than make the GUI wait for whatever you are trying to do

Comment: How can I close context menu? I see no such function avilable... regarding Tast I also don't know how to use it, but I am trying with Marco answer, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, use a Task...

```
    private async void ExecuteProcess_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var errorMessage = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var exceptionMessage = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo Install332 = new ProcessStartInfo();
                Install332.FileName = this.A;
                Install332.Arguments = this.B;
                this.process = Process.Start(Install332);
                this.process.WaitForExit();
                this.finished = true;
                this.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptionMessage = ex.Message;
            }

            return exceptionMessage;
        });

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

It looks like it has been asked before: [WPF ContextMenu still visible after launching an external process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336093/wpf-contextmenu-still-visible-after-launching-an-external-process)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but don't understand how to use a Task... in your code I have error message on await : operator await can only be used in an async method... Also don't understand what it means

Comment: Then you did not copy the whole method... you can see the async keyword there. Have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async. It's very important to understand and use this !

Comment: Ok just noticed "async" added in method name, still with erros but will look a bit more then write here, thanks

Comment: Yes I got it, now it is working better(the application I launch is shown "almost" on front plan), but I still have my context menu that didn't close...
Nicolas advised me to close the context menu, but how can I do this?

Comment: The main thing I cannot understand, is if my click on context menu may open a WindowForm or other WPF, I meet no problem and it closes normally... only if I may execute external process I meet the problem.

Comment: Try the following: Remove the WaitForExit and add an event Handler to the Exited Event: Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited); And do this.finished = true; this.Close();

Comment: Did it, but exactly the same

Comment: There is one guy who did something similar on WPF. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336093/wpf-contextmenu-still-visible-after-launching-an-external-process

Comment: In fact, really the same thing as I have, I understand solution to make a custom MenuItem class, but how can I define/add the customised MenuItem in XAML?